# How to use newtonsoft.Json to serialize and deserialize multiple objects into and out of a list

Tags: json, list, serialization, json.net, deserialization

So I am practising using newtonsoft.Json by creating a very simple Register.

In this code a user enters a first name and last name and this is put into my very simple Person object, which is then put into a List

The user can add multiple people and they are put into the List

My code isn't working and I need help because I am learning.

It isn't working because the serialization and deserialization process is coded wrong I think.

At the beginning of the code a List is declared with the People from the json file

```
List<Person> AllPeopleAdded = new List<Person>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(File.ReadAllText(jsonfilePath)));
```

This is the code showing how the people are added to the json file

```
File.AppendAllText(jsonfilePath,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PeopleAddedThisTime));
```

This is the full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using OOP__Data_Entry__homework.Classes.Person;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace OOP__Data_Entry__homework
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FirstNameText = "Enter A First Name";
        const string LastNameText = "Enter A Last Name";
        const string ContinueText = "Would you Like to Add Another Person, Yes or No";
        const string YesResponse = "Yes";
        const string NoResponse = "No";
        const string ContinueErrorText = "Enter Yes or No";
        const string jsonfilePath = @"C:\OOP- Data Entry- homework\PeopleSaved.json";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //done so that line 29 can work, without swaure brackets there is no list for the List (AllPeopleAdded) to take in
            if(File.Exists(jsonfilePath))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText(jsonfilePath,"[]");
            }

            List<Person> AllPeopleAdded = new List<Person>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(File.ReadAllText(jsonfilePath)));
            List<Person> PeopleAddedThisTime = new List<Person>();

            //done so that the jsonfile(PeopleSaved.json) doesnt error after the new People are added when the user says they do not want to add any more people (line 57)
            if(File.ReadAllText(jsonfilePath).StartsWith("[]"))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(jsonfilePath,"");
            }

            string FirstName;
            string LastName;
            while(true)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(FirstNameText);
                FirstName=Console.ReadLine();
                
                System.Console.WriteLine(LastNameText);
                LastName = Console.ReadLine();

                Person newPerson = new Person(FirstName,LastName);
                PeopleAddedThisTime.Add(newPerson);

                System.Console.WriteLine(ContinueText);
                while(true)
                {
                    string response = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (response==YesResponse)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (response == NoResponse)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(jsonfilePath,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PeopleAddedThisTime));
                        foreach(Person allPersons in AllPeopleAdded)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine($"\n {allPersons.GetFullName()}");
                        }
                        foreach(Person newPersons in PeopleAddedThisTime)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine($"\n {newPersons.GetFullName()}");
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ContinueErrorText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the json file after the code is run once

```
[{"mFirstName":"john ","mLastName":"doe"},{"mFirstName":"Josh","mLastName":"Smith"}]
```

This is the json file after the code is run again
(It is formatted wrong-that is a problem)

```
[{"mFirstName":"john ","mLastName":"doe"},{"mFirstName":"Josh","mLastName":"Smith"}][{"mFirstName":"Serge","mLastName":"Superhero"}]
```

The Person Class

```
using System;

namespace OOP__Data_Entry__homework.Classes.Person
{
    class Person
    {
        public string mFirstName {get; private set; }
        public string mLastName {get; private set; }

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            mFirstName = firstName;
            mLastName = lastName;
        }
        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return mFirstName+" "+mLastName;
        }
    }
}
```

What the json file looks after a couple times the code is run using serge's code

```
[{"mFirstName":null,"mLastName":null},{"mFirstName":null,"mLastName":null},{"mFirstName":"f","mLastName":"f"}]
```

Comment: Can you show a json file code, pls?

Comment: ok give me a minute, I will run my code so it is created

Comment: I will also add the person class if you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deserialize existing json into list, add new person to existing users lists ( or maybe remove some) and after this to serialize the whole list again. Using append will never work, since json always must have only one root element, and you have to insert a new data inside of this root. But you are trying to add the second root and that makes json invalid.

```
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonfilePath))
        json = r.ReadToEnd();

 List<Person> AllPeopleAdded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);

List<Person> PeopleAddedThisTime = new List<Person>();
    
        
    //.....
    
    AllPeopleAdded.AddRange(PeopleAddedThisTime);

    using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(jsonfilePath))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(file, AllPeopleAdded);
    }

 // or  serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
File.WriteAllText(jsonfilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AllPeopleAdded));
```

and fix person class

```
public class Person
{
    public string mFirstName { get; private set; }
    public string mLastName { get; private set; }
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Person(string mFirstName, string mLastName)
    {
        this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
        this.mLastName = mLastName;
    }
    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return mFirstName + " " + mLastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if you have time could you explain the code after the using()

Comment: @Muffin yes, I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: thanks again , i will test it and make sense of this new code 

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the explanation that makes sense

Comment: I have understood the explanation (theory) above and used your code and tried to write my own simpler version of it but when I ran the code the deserialization into the list is not working the values are being returned as null. Also I have tried to say the answer is useful but I need more reputation unfortunately

Comment: I will include what the json looks like after running the code a few times

Comment: @Muffin I added some code to get json from the file. You can try this

Comment: thanks for all this help. the deserializeObject function still seems not to be working its passing on null values to the List

Comment: @Muffin Check path and check json inside of file. I tested it and code is working properly.

Comment: @Muffin  fix Person class, check my update

Comment: Ok it finally works. Everything works. Thank You. But I had to change my Person class (weirdly, i would think). I had my data members properties as private set . So I changed them to set and it works. How does this affect JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ?

Comment: ohhhh, i didnt refresh my page to see your comment ?